# Use Picasso to Place Image Into Drawable

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, picasso

I am attempting to use Picasso from Square to pull a jpg from a URL and then append to an EditText. The reason for Picasso is that it's very lightweight in the implementation. As can be seen I am using a placeholder ImageView, whereby Picasso will import the image from the URL provided, and then I convert that ImageView into a Drawable. The same goes for the ImageGetter.  However I receive null pointer error when using the configuration below. (Note when simply using a drawable from the application resources in place of the 'drawImage' variable below, this configuration works, but I'm trying to extend it to pull resources from a URL).

Is there something out of place here? Or a more efficient way to do this?

Method to append to EditText:

```
public void appendToMessageHistory(String username, String message) {
        if (username != null && message != null) {

            ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

            Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load("http://localhost:3000/uploads/campaign/image/2/2.jpg").into(image);
            Drawable drawImage = image.getDrawable();

            messageHistoryText.append(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + username + ":"
                    + "</b>" + "<br>"));
            messageHistoryText.append(Html.fromHtml(message + "<hr>" + "<br>")
                    + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "");

            messageHistoryText.append(Html.fromHtml("<img src = '"
            + drawImage + "'/>",
            imageGetter, null));

        }
    }
```

The ImageGetter:

```
ImageGetter imageGetter = new ImageGetter() {

@Override
public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
    ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

    Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load("http://localhost:3000/uploads/campaign/image/2/2.jpg").into(image);
    Drawable drawImage = image.getDrawable();

    drawImage.setBounds(0, 0, drawImage.getIntrinsicHeight(), drawImage.getIntrinsicWidth());
    return drawImage;


}
```

};

Comment: post you logcat for error..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is something you miss about Picasso. You can set an annonymous Target class in inTo method like and set bitmap to any object you have :

```
Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load("your url").into(new Target() {

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {


                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom arg1) {
                    // TODO Create your drawable from bitmap and append where you like.

                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) {


                }
            });
```

**EDIT**
so this is how you do that:

```
public void appendToMessageHistory(String username, String message) {
        if (username != null && message != null) {

            ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

            Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load("image url").into(new Target() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom arg1) {
                    Drawable drawImage = new BitmapDrawable(getBaseContext().getResources(),bitmap);
                     messageHistoryText.append(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + username + ":"
                    + "</b>" + "<br>"));
                    messageHistoryText.append(Html.fromHtml(message + "<hr>" + "<br>")
                    + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "");

                    messageHistoryText.append(Html.fromHtml("<img src = '"
                    + drawImage + "'/>",
                    imageGetter, null));    
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) {


                    }
                });




        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you use the methods outlined here? The class structure does not make sense to me...

Comment: just fill the onBitmapLoaded method and create BitmapDrawable in it. Then append to your textEdit as the same way you did before.You don't need to implement all methods listed there. But they all self-explaining.. onPrepareLoad runs just before the loading starts and has a Drawable parameter(which is your placeHolder image)

Comment: Can you walk through how to do that?

Comment: That did not work, it notes: "The method BitmapDrawable(Resources, Bitmap) is undefined for the type new Target(){}" is there another method? at line BitmapDrawable(getBaseContext().getResources,bitmap);

Comment: Can you post the full error log? It does not make sense. You don't have  to use imageGetter method since you already have the bitmap.Are you sure you are using the right "Target" (import com.squareup.picasso.Target)

Comment: Yes, I am using that import but it is not presenting any errors...the messages now to not append whatsoever...just a blank screen

Comment: Do I then call this method, as something like: target.onBitmapLoaded() , so that it actually shows up?

Comment: No, you just declare a callback method there. you don't have to call it manually. It will be called when bitmap is loaded.

Comment: Thank you, I have decided to move to using public static Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) as well as another Thread, much faster implementation