# Populating an array adapter with ImageViews

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

**Please make sure to check the edit, it's important.**

I am taking the Udacity course "Developing Android apps", and they ask us to make an app that loads images of popular movies using TheMovieDB API and display them in a Grid view (and other things as well, but that's irrelevant for now).

I'm also supposed to use Picasso to load the images. (https://square.github.io/picasso/)

So what I did was:

1. Created a blank activity with fragment
2. created a new xml file called **grid_item_movie.xml**
3. Created an adapter which consists of ImageViews instead of Strings
4. Used an Async task to load the images into the adapter

This is my code for **grid_item_movie.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_movie_imageview">

</TextView>
```

---

**Initially I used an ImageView and not a TextView, but my app crashed and it said that I must supply the adpater an id of a TextView.**

---

This is the code for **fragment_main.xml**:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview_movies"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </GridView>

</FrameLayout>
```

And here is *some* of the code of **MainActivityFragment.java** (figured I should show only what's important and not things like how I read the JSON data):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    mMovieAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ImageView>(
            getActivity(),
            R.layout.grid_item_movie,
            R.id.grid_item_movie_imageview,
            new ArrayList<ImageView>());

    GridView movieGrid = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview_movies);
    movieGrid.setAdapter(mMovieAdapter);

    sortMovies newTask = new sortMovies();
    newTask.execute("popularity.desc"); // For now, sort by popularity only

    return rootView;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String[] imagesArray)
{
    if (imagesArray != null)
    {
        mMovieAdapter.clear();
        ImageView posterImage = new ImageView(getContext());
        for (String imageURL : imagesArray)
        {
            Picasso.with(getContext()).load(imageURL).into(posterImage);
            mMovieAdapter.add(posterImage);
        }
    }
}
```

When I launch the app on my phone it, obviously, shows me texts instead of images.

Reading the developer documentation on Array Adapters I understand I need to override the getView() method, but I don't know how to do that. (I know what overriding is, just not what to write inside the method I'm overriding)

What should I do? How do I override, or is there actually a better way?

[image: This is what I'm getting right now]

---

**EDIT:** I have overriden the getView() method like this:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
{
    private final Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> imagesURL;
    public ImageAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<String> objects)
    {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.imagesURL = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View myGridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_movie, parent, false);
        ImageView moviePoster = (ImageView) myGridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_movie_imageview);
        Picasso.with(context).load(imagesURL.get(position)).into(moviePoster);
        return myGridView;
    }
}
```

OnPostExecute is now:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String[] imagesArray)
{
    if (imagesArray != null)
    {
        mMovieAdapter.clear();
        ImageView posterImage = new ImageView(getContext());
        for (String imageURL : imagesArray)
        {
            //Picasso.with(getContext()).load(imageURL).into(posterImage);
            mMovieAdapter.add(imageURL);
        }
    }
}
```

And am declaring the ImageAdapter like this:

```
mMovieAdapter = new ImageAdapter(
        getContext(),
        R.layout.grid_item_movie,
        new ArrayList<String>());
```

Also, the file grid_item_movie now has an ImageView as a root element.
The app doesn't crash but nothing is displayed, why is that?

Comment: Why does **grid_item_movie.xml** contain a TextView when you're trying to display images?

Comment: @RobRose as I've stated - Initially I used an ImageView and not a TextView, but my app crashed and it said that I must supply the adpater an id of a TextView.

Comment: Although I don't know what caused that, I can tell you the reason the text is showing up is because you're trying to load an image into a TextView. It's doing what you told it to do.

Comment: @RobRose I know. The question is, how do I convert it to an ImageView?

Answer (score 1):

The getView method is called once for every item in the list view. But only when the item is visible. So performance is critical when implementing this method and when the user scrolls fast the scrolling will be choppy. It involves reusing views and holding onto references of those views to help increase performance. An excellent tutorial can be found here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html. Its very in-depth and goes over basic and advanced topics. Here is a simple sudocode implementation:

```
private static class ViewHolder {
    // holds onto references to views needed in the list view
 }

getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        // inflate the item view this will be reused as the user scrolls
        // perform tasks that are the same across all items
    }

    // perform tasks that are different for each item

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but you need to understand I'm a beginner. I need to know how to convert the TextViews `I have to use` into ImagesViews, doing all this using the Picasso service.

Comment: You cant convert a TextView to an ImageView, but all View's have a method setBackgroundResource(int resourceId) and you can call that to set the background to a resource you have. For example if you have a background image called item_background.png in the drawable folder you can call anyView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.item_background);

Comment: You're right, but like I said, I'm getting the images from the internet using the Picasso service (https://square.github.io/picasso/). The images are not received from the drawable folder, so I can't use setBackgroundResource() or setImageResource().

Comment: This answer might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151926/use-picasso-to-place-image-into-drawable it shows how to set the image into a Target. In the onBitmapLoaded method the first line converts the bitmap into a drawable. Then you can ignore the rest and just call aTextView.setBackground(theDrawable); and I would think that should work.