# How to store image in bitmap variable from picasso

Tags: java, android

I download image from url using picasso.But, i don't know how to store that image in bitmap variable.Please anyone help me!

Here my code:

```
Bitmap bitmapImage = null;
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .into(new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                }
            });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: USe this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151926/use-picasso-to-place-image-into-drawable

Answer (score 0):

it's already stored in bitmap var of ***onBitmapLoaded*** method , so you have just to take it in another bitmap var that declared in a global scope or whatever scope you want .

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap bitmapImage = null;
Picasso.with(context)
        .load(url)
        .into(new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
             bitmapImage = bitmap;

            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

            }
        });
```