# Android : Adding an imageview right at the end of a textview via ImageSpan and make the image clickable

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring, spannablestringbuilder, imagespan

[image]

I want to achieve a design as shown above in the screenshot. The image is fetched from a URL and I want to add a click listener in the image only. Tried using Image span but with no success. Could somebody help me through this?

Thank you

Comment: You have an image downloaded but need to incorporate it into the text and then make just the image clickable. Is that right or are you looking for help getting the image from the URL? Can you share you code to get the image?

Comment: Yes sir, I can download the image and place it in an imageview using Picasso library. But need to add that image just at the end of the text

Comment: Can you add the _ImageSpan_ so it shows up in the text? It would be helpful to show some of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more complete answer to your question. I use a drawable resource, but you can create a drawable from your bitmap. See the following code for a description. This code can be placed into the `onCreate()` of your main activity (or elsewhere.)

[image]

```
// Get a string that can be spanned with an ImageSpan and a ClickableSpan.
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Some text ");
// This will be the image. I use a resource here, but there are constructors that can
// accept a Drawable. See BitmapDrawable at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable#BitmapDrawable(android.content.res.Resources,%20android.graphics.Bitmap)

ImageSpan imgSpan = new ImageSpan(this, R.drawable.ic_baseline_airplanemode_active_24, ImageSpan.ALIGN_CENTER);
ClickableSpan cs = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(@NonNull View widget) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

// The image will overlay the last blank in the text.
ss.setSpan(imgSpan, ss.length() - 1, ss.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
// The clickable span will overlay the image from the ImageSpan.
ss.setSpan(cs, ss.length() - 1, ss.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
// Just a TextView.
TextView myView = findViewById(R.id.myView);
myView.setText(ss);
// Prevent the ImageSpan from showing a highlight on click.
myView.setHighlightColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
// Make sure the TextView can be clicked.
myView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Thank you great example. But I would have to set the image from a URL. How would I do that?

Comment: @viper If you are using Picasso [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25154748/6287910) is an example of how to go about it. In `onBitMapLoaded()` you will create a _BitmapDrawable_ from the bitmap and set the _Drawable_ where you need it. You will need Internet permission in the manifest and make sure that you update the UI on the main thread. You may need to do some additional manipulation to the bitmap to change size, etc. depending on your needs.

Comment: @viper Also, make sure your _Target_ is not garbage collected before you need it. This seems to be an issue that some have with Picasso.

Answer (score 1):

You can set another span call `ClickableSpan` at the same place of the `ImageSpan`. Here an example code:

```
builder.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(@NonNull View widget) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "icon clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        },
                builder.length() - 1,
                builder.length(),
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        holder.tvTitle.setText(builder);
        holder.tvTitle.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

It is important to setMovementMethod for the click to work.

Comment: I also haven't added image using image span in the first place. The image is loaded from the URL. How can I do that?

Comment: just add it dynamically when you set build the SpannableString.

Comment: I want to add image in text. I guess Spannable String is just for strings?

Comment: SpannableString helps you do a lot more with styling string. Search for it and explore yourself

Answer (score -1):

I don't know your limitation, but you can using a layout like bellow:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:padding="5dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/top_tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Papaya (Around)"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=",(2kg)"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_tv"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/top_tv"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_help"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/bottom_tv"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/bottom_tv"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/bottom_tv"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and using setOnClickListener for ImageView. The result:

[image]

Comment: Well there won't be 2 textviews. The Papaya (around, 2KG) is a single text view which might come in 2 lines

Comment: @viper you can split the text, set before "," in top textview and rest in bellow.

Comment: I would not know when the text will go to next line to fit